# Broken migrations with Django sites framework to restrict URLs access

Tags: python, django, multisite, django-sites

I want to share single code-base Django (2.2) over 2 URLs : `foo.domain.ltd` & `bar.domain.ltd`.

- on `foo.domain.ltd`: all the Django URLs are available
- on `bar.domain.ltd`: only some URLs are available, all other return 403 error

I expected using the [*sites framework*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/sites/) (`django.contrib.sites`) to reach this goal :

- 1 code base
- 2 *domains* configured in the *sites framework*
- 2 `gunicorn` instances with appropriate configuration :

  - `core.settings.foo` with `SITE_ID = 1`
  - `core.settings.bar` with `SITE_ID = 2`
- 1 `nginx` server listening clients and forwarding requests to the appropriate `gunicorn` instance depending the `xxx.domain.ltd` used

The issue I encountered is that *sites framework* looks like *model oriented* : You can associate `models` to one, two (…) `sites`.

I try to set `urls` depending on the `sites`, but I broke the `./manage migrate` tool…

1) Settings the *sites framework* to my project and a `dualsite` app to host associated code :

**`core.settings`** :

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # (…)
    "django.contrib.sites",
    "dualsite.apps.DualsiteConfig",
 ]
```

**`core.settings.foo`** :

```py
from core.settings import *

SITE_ID = 1
```

**`core.settings.bar`** :

```py
from core.settings import *

SITE_ID = 2
```

**`dualsite.migration.0001_set_sites`** :

```py
from django.db import migrations

def my_sites(apps, schema_editor):
    Site = apps.get_model("sites", "Site")

    initial_site = Site.objects.get(id=1)
    initial_site.domain = "foo.domain.ltd"
    initial_site.name = "foo"
    initial_site.save()

    Site.objects.create(domain="bar.domain.ltd", name="bar")

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [("sites", "0002_alter_domain_unique")]

    operations = [migrations.RunPython(my_sites)]
```

At this point `./manage.py migrate` fails :

```py
  Applying sites.0001_initial... OK
  Applying sites.0002_alter_domain_unique... OK
  Applying dualsite.0001_set_sites...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "./manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File ".venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File ".venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File ".venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File ".venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File ".venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File ".venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 234, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File ".venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File ".venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File ".venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 245, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File ".venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File ".venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/special.py", line 190, in database_forwards
    self.code(from_state.apps, schema_editor)
  File "dualsite/migrations/0001_set_sites.py", line 6, in my_sites
    initial_site = Site.objects.get(id=1)
  File ".venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File ".venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 408, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
__fake__.DoesNotExist: Site matching query does not exist.
```

…**but it works** if I split the migration : `./manage.py migrate sites; ./manage.py migrate`

2) Now that my DB is set, it is time to restrict URLs depending the `SITE_ID` set in `core.settings.xxx` :

**`dualsite.utils`** :

```py
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
from django.views.generic import TemplateView as tw

def check_site(view_asked):

    view_returned = tw.as_view(template_name="403.dhtml")

    if Site.objects.get_current().name == "foo":
        view_returned = view_asked

    return view_returned
```

**`core.urls`** :

```py
from django.urls import include, path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView as tw
from dualsite.utils import check_site

urlpatterns = [
    # restricted : only foo.domain.ltd
    path("", check_site(tw.as_view(template_name="base.dhtml")), name="home"),
    path("hellofoo/", check_site(include("hellofoo.urls"))),
    # full access : foo.domain.ltd & bar.domain.ltd
    path("about/", tw.as_view(template_name="about.dhtml"), name="about"),
    path("helloworld/", include("helloworld.urls")),
]
```

*Hooray* : **The URLs restriction works!!!**

**but** `./manage.py migrate sites` is now broken :

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "./manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File ".venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File ".venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File ".venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File ".venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 361, in execute
    self.check()
  File ".venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File ".venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 65, in _run_checks
    issues.extend(super()._run_checks(**kwargs))
  File ".venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File ".venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File ".venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File ".venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File ".venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 398, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File ".venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File ".venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 579, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File ".venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File ".venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 572, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "core/urls.py", line 7, in <module>
    path("", check_site(tw.as_view(template_name="base.dhtml")), name="home"),
  File "dualsite/utils.py", line 9, in check_site
    if Site.objects.get_current().name == "foo":
  File ".venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sites/models.py", line 58, in get_current
    return self._get_site_by_id(site_id)
  File ".venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sites/models.py", line 30, in _get_site_by_id
    site = self.get(pk=site_id)
  File ".venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File ".venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 402, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File ".venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 256, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File ".venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1242, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File ".venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 55, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File ".venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1100, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File ".venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File ".venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File ".venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File ".venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File ".venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File ".venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File ".venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 383, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: django_site
```

At this point I decided to get help on *StackOverflow*…

**Question** : Is the *Django sites framework* an adequate tool to restrict URLs access depending on *domain names* used ?

**Bonus question** :

- *if yes* : Where am I wrong to broke *migrate* tool?
- *if no* : Which tool can I use to keep access rules *in Django* (instead of putting it in Nginx)

Thanks in advance !

Comment: please post a minimal viable question. No one has the time to read such long questions

Comment: Sorry, this overbrain a bit myself last days… I cannot reduce this question yet…